# get contact list with yahoo api

Tags: oauth, yahoo-api

i wanna use yahoo api for get user yahoo contact and show in a page my code:

```
// if a session is initialized, fetch the user's profile information
    if($session) {
    // Get the currently sessioned user.
      $user = $session->getSessionedUser();
    //var_dump($user);

    // Load the profile for the current user.
    $profile = $user->getProfile();
    $profile_contacts=XmltoArray($user->getContactSync());
    var_dump( $profile_contacts);
    $contacts=array();
    foreach($profile_contacts['contactsync']['contacts'] as $key=>$profileContact){
      foreach($profileContact['fields'] as $contact){
        $contacts[$key][$contact['type']]=$contact['value'];
       }
     }
  //echo "<pre/>";
  //print_r($contacts);exit; 
  }
```

but $contact is emty,i dont have idea help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can see the response in this way
 $response = $user->getContacts();
Var_dump($response);
and find your problem